# DatePickerDialog header background color

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I've setup a style for a DatePickerDialog background, and it shows up differently on Nexus 5 (Marshmallow):

[image]

The style I'm using is:

```
<style name="datepicker">
    <item name="android:background">@color/android:white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/android:black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/android:black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/android:black</item>
</style>
```

(`colorAccent` is gold)

The year at the top is supposed to be controlled by `textColorSecondary`, but now it's showing up as black. And the background of the header is grey, which I'd like white. What are the names of these items for Marshmallow?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use this `style` and `theme` config for change the text and header color. However, I think it is not more beautiful than default dialog picker.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/MyDatePickerDialogTheme</item>

</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#000</item> <!-- header date, month color && calendar text highlight color -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">#000</item> <!-- header year color -->

    <item name="android:colorAccent">#B09A60</item> <!-- button color -->
</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">#fff</item> <!-- header background color -->
</style>
```

Tested on API 22, 23, 25
[image]

Comment: I had to specify `<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>` instead of `<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>` for the buttons but this is good!

Answer (score 0):

The names of these items are the same for all android version > Andoid 5.0 Lollipop to be complient with Material design.

You can try to add a parent and override headerBackground for the background :

```
<style name="datepicker" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:background">@color/android:white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/android:black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/android:black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/android:black</item>
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/android:white</item>
</style>
```

However i think the year color is the same that textColorPrimary.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The year changed (somehow?), the header background didn't. It's still grey.

Comment: You override <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme"> in your app theme , or you are using this style directly in the code ?

Comment: Directly in the code. As a test I added it in the app theme and removed it from the code and I get the same display.