# How can I change DatePickerDialog Header color background with my own customization? [Not Solved]

Tags: android

[image]

**NOTE:** This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46046058/datepickerdialog-header-background-color) is not accurate. The problem in that accepted answer is it changes the footer color also.

***I just want to change header color to black.***

**Please Note:** Other things should not be change. For button, I sat button color programatically, which is perfect and date selected circle background color also should not be changed. Becasue I'm trying from last 6 hrs, but no luck.

I'm trying on 6.0.1
Code:

```
  <style name="dialog_picker_theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog">
        <item name="android:background">#303030</item>

        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#424242</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
        <item name="android:headerBackground">#000000</item> <!-- header background color -->
    </style>
```

And, I use this theme (dialog_picker_theme) in my datapickerdialog.

Answer (score 0):

Apply preferred header color to the attribute `android:textColorPrimaryInverse` on your app's Base Application Theme:

```
  <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```